# Retrieving sequence of Review Tasks Results (within a date)?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, data-explorer, sorting

Is it possible to know (be sure) the sequence of review tasks results, even though the **time** data from 'CreationDate' is removed (i.e., there is only date, not time)?

Let me explain better. I want to know the sequence of actions a post receive in the  Close Vote review queue. For this I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(100) p.Id AS [Post Link],
                rtrt.Name AS [Review Task Result Name],
                rtr.CreationDate [Date from Review Task Result],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.Id ORDER BY rtr.CreationDate ASC) AS [Sequence] 
FROM PostsWithDeleted p
INNER JOIN ReviewTasks rt ON rt.PostId = p.Id
INNER JOIN ReviewTaskResults rtr ON rtr.ReviewTaskId = rt.Id
INNER JOIN ReviewTaskResultTypes rtrt ON rtrt.Id = rtr.ReviewTaskResultTypeId
WHERE rt.ReviewTaskTypeId = 2 -- Close Votes review queue
      AND rt.ReviewTaskStateId = 2 -- Review was completed
      AND rtr.ReviewTaskResultTypeId IN (5, 6, 8) -- Edit, Close, Do not close; respectively
      AND p.CreationDate < GETDATE() - 15
ORDER BY p.Id DESC,
         rtr.CreationDate ASC;
```

I tracked the order of Review Tasks Results from two posts returned by the query, and the sequence in them seemed to be correct:

- Example 1: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21970197.
- Example 2: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/22101899.

Was it a coincidence? If it is not a coincidence how is it possible the sequence is correct if `rtr.CreationDate` has no time data, only date; and there are multiple actions within a unique date?

I think I am lacking some understanding in how SQL sorting works generally and/or with datetime datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReviewTaskResults` has a primary key `Id`, which is highly likely to have an auto increment. So you can just sort on `Id` instead of on `CreationDate`.

Comment: There are a few cases where race conditions might alter the order if you would look at timestamps but I highly doubt you would find many within this specific table. Also note that the Id might not be [consecutive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291853/158100) and that is not only due to deletes.